# Protractor and Fitnesse

Tags: node.js, selenium, selenium-webdriver, protractor

Is it possible to run protractor with fitnesse.
I.e. specify the test case in fitnesse and have it call protractor in the fixturing?

I want to be able to run protractor like selenium grid with remote webdriver, where we have a node and hub setup, and instantiate a session by defining capabilities for anew remote webdriver instance. Is this sort of thing possible if you want to use fitnesse instead of node.js?

Thanks,
Rahul

Comment: have you found a way to do this in the meantime? I would like to do this too

Comment: Use this tutorial to bind your fitnesse pages to your protractor backend and create custom assertions. https://datqaguy.wordpress.com/2015/08/18/finesse-test-using-slim-and-python/

If it works, do let me know, I will post a complete answer which you can accept.